# How can use Ef Core Migration for JetBrains Rider

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

I'm using JetBrains Rider IDE. I want use code first but I can't find Package Manager Console in JetBrains Rider. I want to work on EF Core.

Comment: Use the dotnet ef command!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package Manager Console is a feature of Visual Studio. You cannot use these tools in Rider.

You need to install an extension to the dotnet CLI instead:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Then you can execute commands using `dotnet ef`.

Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet

Answer (score 1):

I think using the Entity Framework Core Inside Rider: UI Way with the latest Rider 2022.3 is not working for me, it kept throwing java.NullException error, have been on this like 2 days not until I find another way around this by installing EntityFramework 7 locally using dotnet tools manifest. As follows:

- Open your terminal
- run => dotnet new tool-manifest
- You’ll receieve a successful message that your dotnet tools manifest is successfully added
- run => dotnet tool install dotnet-ef (to install dotnet-ef 7)
- EntityFramework Core 7 will be installed for you
- You can check if dotnet-ef is now installed and ready to be used by
  run => dotnet tool run dotnet-ef

With the above infomation you can now run your migration code using your Rider terminal or other CLI.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `dotnet ef` directly, it's worth mentioning the [Entity Framework Core UI](https://github.com/seclerp/rider-efcore#readme) plugin which also provides a way to create and apply migrations.